# Exit function after certain time in C++

Tags: c++, time, tree, exit

I have a function that has exponential complexity (the contents of which cannot be modified):

```cpp
void exponential_func(int depth){
  // recursively search a tree and extract best value
  return value;
}
```

This function is called iteratively

```cpp
void call_exponential_function(int max_depth){
  for(int i = 1; i < max_depth; i++){
    cout << exponential_func(i) << endl;
  }
}
```

I want to get the deepest search I can within a certain time limit. For example, the time limit is 60 seconds. Calling `exponential_func(i)` takes 30s in total for i=1 to 5. `exponential_func(6)` takes 120s. How can I stop the execution of `call_exponential_function`  when the time is up?

Comment: `recursively search a tree and extract best value` -> `recursively search a tree and extract best value and also check if time limit is reached`

Comment: Where would you check if the time limit is reached?

Comment: Probably right at the top of each call. Then you have to decide if you're going to return a code to signal failure or throw an exception. Depending on the complexity of the recursive function, either could be more attractive.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question to make it clearer. Checking time before the call does not work as you do not know how long `exponential_func` will take to complete (only that it will take longer). The function needs to be stopped while executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to make `exponential_func` cooperatively exit when it is told to do so, by passing in a time deadline.

If it's literally impossible to modify that function, then you can run it on a separate thread, and terminate the thread when the deadline is up.  **However**, this risks leaving data that `exponential_func` was using (which may include global data structures such as the heap) in a corrupted state.  So it is typically not good practice to do this, and I only offer it as a hypothetical idea.

So a better option in this case would be to spawn another process that accepts data via some sort of IPC, runs `exponential_func`, retrieves results via IPC, and can be terminated if it passes the deadline.  If I were writing production-ready code, this is what I'd do.